# ¿Cómo llamo una función de un archivo PHP con JavaScript sin utilizar eventos?

Tags: php, javascript

Deseo llamar una función que tengo en un archivo .php (consulta.php), y tengo un .js (prueba.js)

En el archivo .js tengo esto:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'consulta.php',
            data: {functionName: 'validaNumeiden'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.msg); 
            }
     }
}
```

y en el .php tengo esto (aclaro es solo una prueba pero no llama la función):

```
public function validaNumeiden($acti_usua)
  {
echo "prueba";
}
```

Comment: `onload()` es un evento 

Answer (score 1):

Tienes los siguientes puntos por corregir:

- `public` es un modificador de acceso válido, solamente cuando al elemento que se lo aplicas existe dentro del contexto de una clase
- Cuando declaras el cuerpo de una función, solo estás indicando lo que hará pero no en que momento, entonces se hace necesario que la invoques con la sintaxis de: **`funcionNombre()`**
- En la función estás indicando el paso de un argumento por medio del parámetro: **`$acti_usua`** pero no le das dicho valor por lo cual recibirás un mensaje de error
- En el backend debes emplear el método `json_encode()` para lograr el resultado esperado
- Ojo con lo que mandas en data pues ahi es un objeto y la impresión que obtengas es la cadena de texto ya que eso es lo que estás mandando

Tu PHP debería quedar así:

```
function imprimeJson()
{
    return json_encode(["message" => $_POST["functionName"] ]); 
}

echo imprimeJson();
```

Y tu frontend debería quedar así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'consulta.php',
                    data: {functionName: 'validaNumeiden'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response.message); 
                    }
             })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```